# Can Windows create the "CreateExplorerShellUnelevatedTask" task in Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have the `CreateExplorerShellUnelevatedTask` active and wonder if this is a leftover created by some third-party program such as (now-deleted) CCleaner or by Windows (10) itself.

- action: start a program
- details: `C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE /NOUACCHECK`
- "Author" is marked as `ExplorerShellUnelevated` for unknown reasons.
- location: `\`

Comment: Windows explorer don't allow you to create it elevated. The mechanism for this is Task Scheduler. If you were to start a program from an elevated program that program will be elevated. That's not allowed for Explorer. So if you start Explorer it will run a task to start it unelevated. The important thing to remember is that there is no way to unelevated a program.